# PHP insert statement not working :(

Tags: php, mysql

The error message I get is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''Player Name', 'Player Age', 'Player Team') VALUES ('Willian', '27', 'Chelsea')' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebProgrammingWebsite\add-player.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\WebProgrammingWebsite\add-player.php(9): PDO->prepare('INSERT INTO pla...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebProgrammingWebsite\add-player.php on line 9

I have double checked and tried to change what is written on line 9 like it says but I just can't get it to work. I have also tried to use the whole "Bind_param" thing but I'm just a noob and nothing is working. It has to be some dumb syntax mistake on my part but it's driving me crazy
Here is my code:

```
<?php
  require("connect.php");

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['p_name'];
    $age = $_POST['p_age'];
    $team = $_POST['p_team'];

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO player ('Player Name', 'Player Age', 'Player Team') VALUES ('".$name."', '".$age."', '".$team."')");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->closeCursor();

    header("Location: display-players.php");
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Football Database</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <form class="add" action="" method="post">
          <label>Player Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="p_name"><br>

          <label>Player Age</label>
          <input type="text" name="p_age"><br>

          <label>Player Team</label>
          <input type="text" name="p_team"><br>

          <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
      </div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: seen this error all too many times

Comment: Remember that error message. It will serve you well next time.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: Thanks everyone got it sorted, sorry for the duplicate. I thought I am using prepared statements to prevent Injection Attack?

Comment: Your columns have spaces in them which is, for most seasoned developers, *super annoying* because they require special escaping when used. You should steer towards column names that are short, concise, and self-explanatory. `playerName` or `player_name` is vastly better than `Player Name`.

Comment: You've got half of it right, you're using prepared statements, but you're not using placeholder values, and that's where the magic happens. You should avoid putting `$x` type values directly in your query, or using concatenation, that's text-book injection. Instead use a placeholder and on `execute()` call it.

Comment: @tadman right ill have to learn about that haha thank you

Comment: Step 1: `$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO player (\`Player Name\`, \`Player Age\`, \`Player Team\`) VALUES (:name., :age, :team.)");`. Step 2: `$stmt->execute(array('name' => $_POST['p_name'], ...))`. Note the backticks on the column names, as single quotes designate string data, not columns.

Comment: It's not that hard to do in practice, and usually makes your queries a lot less messy, and so, easier to understand and find bugs.

Comment: I attempted to try it out given the example you gave. I wrote

Comment: $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO player (`Player Name`, `Player 
    Age`, `Player Team`) VALUES (:name., :age, :team.)");
        $stmt->execute(array('name' => $name, 'age' => $age, 'team' => 
    $team));

Comment: and i got an error, I'm guessing I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Since this question has been closed, open a new one with the new code you're using and the exact error you're getting. I'm sure you're closer to solving this now.

Comment: @tadman I'll have to wait another 90 mins to ask another question haha

Comment: @tadman nevermind I fixed it. I got rid of the two periods that were infront of and behind the placeholders in the insert statement

Comment: @Cian Gives you some time to hack around with it for a bit. Have a look at guides [like this](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) or [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) if you're really stuck.